# Next.js : router.push not refreshing the page

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, next-router

I'm building a next.js page `/page/data/[dataId]` (this page is navigated when A user clicks on a link from page `/page/data` , I fetch the list of items through an API ).

When user clicks on a button , I call an API to delete this item from DB . Once the API call is successful. I need to redirect user back to `/page/data` page . Here's how I'm doing it :

```js
 async function removeData(){

    // ... some logic

    await removeData({input});
    setTimeout(()=>{
          router.push("/page/data"); // redirecting to parent
     },2000)

}
```

Once the user is redirected back to `/page/data/` I need to refresh the list of data items bacause I want to remove the item which got deleted. Now the problem is - The `/page/data/` is not getting refreshed after navigating it through  `router.push`.

I know we can achieve this by replacing `router.push` to `window.location="/page/data"`
but that is very expensive way.

I also tried :

```js
router.push("/page/data",undefined,{shallow:false})
```

but it didn't work.

Anyone can you help me how can we achieve this in optimal way ? I find `window.location` approach too expensive.

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you mean by "The parent is not getting refreshed after navigating [to] it..."? What needs to be refreshed? Is the parent component already mounted and just needs to refetch something? Can you include all the relevant code you are working with? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 7):

The workaround I have found is to add a query parameter.

For example:

`router.push({ pathname: "/page/data", query: { u: "true" } });`

So it will redirect to `/page/data?u=true` and the presence of the query param will force a new getServerSideProps call. I just chose `u` to signify "update". This works for me but I realise it's a bit of a hack.

In response to the other answer, it's not limited to deleting an element without a page reload. In my case, I navigate from a page of many items to a separate page to create a new item. On submitting the form on this separate page, I redirect with router.push to the index page, but the new item is not there. I am not sure your suggestion is suitable in this instance.

Comment: I think, these `useRouter` properties are not available in latest version of `NextJS`, `next/navigation`

Answer (score 4):

I was into this situation for days...
What worked for me:
Call `router.refresh()` before `router.push(path)` in the origin page.
It might not sound or look as the best solution but it does the job in this case where you need to refetch data.

Example:

```
router.refresh()
router.push("/page/data")
```

In my case it also enabled the refetch of the destination page server side functions.
I'm not a web expert, I'm just saying what worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

For next.js app router:

MACROSystems' approach didn't work for me, but led me to the right track.
The correct approach should change the order of the two lines:

```js
router.push("/page/data")
router.refresh()
```

What it does:

1. Navigate back to the redirected page first.
2. Refetch data from the server and merge it into current page. (Here is the redirected page)

If we call `refresh` first, then next.js will refetch the page before the redirect. If something only exists on the redirected page and not on the current page, that data might not be updated.

Answer (score 1):

You can purge the cached-data for a specific route on the server side using the `revalidatePath` method as described in the Docs [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/revalidatePath#revalidating-a-specific-url).

```
import { revalidatePath } from 'next/cache'

async function doStuff() {

    // ... some logic

    revalidatePath("/page/data")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because Next not fetching new data from the server when you navigate to the previous page. You can use `router.reload()` for hark reload, but instead after deleting an item from DB, you can try to update your local data with something like `newData = oldData.filter(data => data !== deletedData)` instead of fetching it from the server. You shouldn't reload an application after the initial render, in common.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

I have used this method in the past, like you say it may be an expensive approach but it keeps the routing without 'next router' compared to moving part of the routing to `window.location`.

```
router.push('ROUTE').then(() => window.location.reload())
```

Next router also has a reload function that could be called, but it still uses the principles of after the route.

```
router.push('ROUTE').then(() => router.reload())
```

Comment: If we are moving to a new page , isn't `router` going to be destroyed ? I mean can refresh parent from child page ?

Comment: I have just tried routing with `router.reload()` after and it doesn't have an issue even though you are routing to a new page that may not have the router imported on.

Comment: Sorry but it is similar to window reload, this will be my last option.